# How do I solve $5x=x^2+8$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I solve the following equation for x?
$$5x=x^2+8$$

Comment: And what does this have to do with "similarly of triangles"?

Comment: @gerrymyerson I didn't post the whole question only what I needed help with, but the section I'm learning about is called similar triangles.

Comment: Fine, but doesn't it make sense to give a title that actually corresponds to the question? Won't that make it easier on the next person to come along?

Comment: Yes you are most definitely correct my sinceriously apology for not knowing how to use this app, but  now are you going to help or just criticize the title?

Comment: This quadratic has no real roots so there may be something wrong with your work leading up to this

Comment: The quadratic @David Quinn speaks about is $x^2-5x+8=0$. Maybe, **you haven't yet learned the general formulas giving the solutions of a quadratic**. In this case, let us write this equation under the form $(x^2-2*2.5x+2.5^2)+1.75=0$ (do you agree ?) then $(x+2.5)^2+1.75=0$, but this has no solution because the square of any "real" number is positive, and when added to 1.75 cannot be 0.

Comment: I *am* helping by criticizing the title, and you're *not* helping by refusing to change it. Also, I believe that at the time I posted my comments there was an earlier comment that showed you what to do with the mathematics, but that comment is gone now. In any event, I hope the comments from David Quinn and JeanMarie have helped you.

Comment: somethings wrong. the numbers you give us lead to no solution.

Comment: The best answer so far is JeanMaries comment. You can and should always solve this via "completing the square" (s. e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square). Meaning try to write this as $a(x-b)^2+c=0$ and first solve this for $(x-b)^2$ and then solving that for $x$. All the other concrete formulas are hard to remember and just applied of this stuff above.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2-5x+8 = 0$

$\left(\frac{-b +\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)$

and

$\left(\frac{-b -\sqrt {b^2-4ac}}{2a}\right)$

plugging in $a = 1, b = -5, c = 8$.

$x = 2.5 + 1.3228756555323i, x = 
2.5 - 1.3228756555323i$.

I am quite confident thats not what you need for your problem.

Comment: Um... $(x=3)(x-2)\neq x^2-5x+8$. You just simply *cannot* have that identity.

Comment: @Frank I've fixed it now. Lmao

Answer (score 1):

Completing the square:
$$\left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^{2} = -8 + \left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{2}$$

I need to add $\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{2}$ to RHS because if we expand LHS we will have an extra term of $\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)^{2}$. Simplify the RHS and we get

$$\left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right)^{2} = -\frac{7}{4}$$

then take the square root to get

$$\left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right) = \sqrt\frac{7}{4} \times \sqrt{-1} \implies \left(x - \frac{5}{2}\right) = \sqrt\frac{7}{4} \times i$$

use that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ and we have $-1 \times  \frac{7}{4}$. The square root of $-1 = i$ so we have

$$x = \frac{5}{2} \pm \sqrt\frac{7}{4} \times i$$

Comment: Please don't post only formulas without any explanation. This yields nearly never a good answer. Try extending this with some explanations of what you are doing/why these equations holds.

Comment: I will add some explanation.

Comment: @ctst I have added some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> **Concept:** A good way to see how many solutions a quadratic has is to look at its Discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$. \begin{align*} & \text{When } D>0:\text{The quadratic has }2\text{ real solutions}\\ & \text{When }D=0:\text{ The quadratic has 1 real solution}\\ & \text{When }D<0:\text{ The quadratic has no real solutions}\end{align*}

Looking at the quadratic, $x^2-5x+8=0$, we see that $a=1,b=-5,c=8$. So the discriminant is $$D=b^2-4ac=25-32<0$$
Implying that the quadratic has no real solutions.

---

Perhaps something went wrong when you did the Geometry?